# Optimize query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, optimization, indexing

I have a query in Sql Server that I will like to optimize.

```
SELECT user_type_name = CASE user_type_id 
                          WHEN 1 THEN 'Admin' 
                          WHEN 5 THEN 'Super Admin' 
                          WHEN 3 THEN 'Writer' 
                          WHEN 4 THEN 'Reader' 
                        END, 
       user_can_log = CASE user_inactive 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'No' 
                        ELSE 'Yes' 
                      END, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM   t_fthread 
        WHERE  fthread_creator_userid = user_id)         AS number_tickets, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM   t_email 
        WHERE  email_to LIKE '%' + user_email + '%' 
                OR email_cc LIKE '%' + user_email + '%') AS number_emails, 
       * 
FROM   t_user 
       LEFT JOIN t_organisation 
         ON user_org_id = organisation_id 
WHERE  user_org_id = 42 
ORDER  BY user_last_name, 
          user_first_name
```

The query takes too much time to run. thanks to query analyzer, I've identified the part in the query that takes too much time,
It's this section:

```
(select count(*) from t_email where email_to like '%'+user_email+'%' or email_cc like '%'+user_email+'%') as number_emails.
```

I'm trying to rewrite the query to still get the number_emails but in every case, it's still very slow.

I've tried to create the indexes, but it's impossible to create index on user_email and user_cc. Both columns are ntext types and on sql server 2000, it's not possible to create index on theses columns.
I've run analyze the query with Database Engine Tune Advisor and I've run the recommendations provided by the tools.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_t_fthread_15_2073058421__K5] ON [dbo].[t_fthread]
(
[fthread_creator_userid] ASC
)

CREATE STATISTICS [_dta_stat_1365579903_4_3] ON [dbo].[t_user]([user_last_name], [user_first_name])

CREATE STATISTICS [_dta_stat_1365579903_1_5] ON [dbo].[t_user]([user_id], [user_org_id])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_t_user_15_1365579903__K5_K1] ON [dbo].[t_user]
(
[user_org_id] ASC,
[user_id] ASC
)
```

But the query still takes lot of time to finish the execution.

Comment: Its also impossible to use an index in SQL Server if you have `LIKE '%foo'` so it wouldn't matter if you could index the column.

Answer (score 3):

Your query indicates bad design. You should either

- normalize your database if all users from to and cc are in your database, or
- keep a track of number of emails sent

### Normalize your database

Requirement: all users from to and cc are in your database (no emails sent to email addresses out of organization)

Instead of storing emails in `to` and `cc`, create new tables and store email id as well as user_ids from to and cc.

### Keep a track of number of emails sent

Add two columns (`Number_To, Number_CC`) in `t_user` table and increment them as needed (when sending emails, storing it to `t_email` table, ...). If You decide to go this way, watch out for concurrency, it is best to do `UPDATE t_user SET Number_To = Number_To + 1` instead of selecting current `Number_To` value and then updating to new value.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do the search using:

```
 email_to like user_email+'%'
```

, or even code all alternatives?
Or, even better, store the user email (that will being searched for later) in a "cleansed" form in the database?

The wildcard in front of user_email is the evil one: textual searches starting with '%' will always be slow, because they're unpredictable, and you'll never know where in the string the search text will be found.

For example, consider the text:

```
kakaka@mailblahblah.youknowka@this.text
```

While this is a relatively small string, the search for the text "ka@this.text" will go like this

- "k" found on position one
- match still on position two
- mismatch on position three

this goes two times on, and the third time the ''@'' is found. Then mismatch at position four.

Only after about 36 comparison-operations, SQL Server knows the string matches. And that is for one row only.. So try to avoid wildcards at the beginning of string comparisons.

Comment: No we cannont do the search with only email_to like user_email+'%'  because the field  email_to can contains many email so if the 1st wildcard is removed, the query won't return accurate results

Comment: Then store the mail adresses in another table (cleansed, one per row), with a many-to-one relation from the mail adresses table to the current table. Perform the search in the mail adresses table, eventually via a join.

Comment: THen go back and tell whoever designed the database in total ignroance of database design guidelineys that he is responsible. It should not be a ntext (emails are not that long) and should only contain ONE email. It is called RELATIONAL database for a reason, which the designer ignored. As result, your performance sucks.

Comment: @TomTom: Not entirely true. We don't know what the purpose of the table is - maybe the only function is to log email messages? Or is this a function later introduced in the database? But I agree with you: In each of these cases, it would be beneficial to re-wire the storage of emails and have a normalized DB-scheme. (besides, a relational DB isn't necessarily a normalized DB)

Comment: @TomTom, the person who design the DB put ntext because those fields are suppose to contains mailing list (you can't define in advance how many mails will be inside that mailing list)...Now, I can't re-write the storage of emails but that might be for the future...Thanks for your help though

Comment: Well, the person defsining this - working for me- would not look for a job at McDonalds. Just as a note for how bad a job he did.

Comment: @fisdelom: that's not a good reason - if you design a normalized database, you have one table for all mailinglists, and another with mail addresses and a foreign key to the first table. Just a many-to-one relationship..

Answer (score 0):

Try this query once. Also, try `=` operator instead `LIKE`

```
SELECT tu.*,

(case when  user_type_id = 1 then 'Admin' 
       when user_type_id = 5 then 'Super Admin' 
       when user_type_id = 3 then 'Writer' 
       when user_type_id = 4 then  'Reader'
       else 'somethingelse' 
       end) as user_type_name, 

    (case when user_inactive = 1 then 'No'
     else 'Yes' end) as user_can_log,

    (select count(*) as number_tickets from  t_fthread where
    fthread_creator_userid=user_id()),

    (select count(*) as number_emails from  t_email where email_to like '%abc@xyz.com%'
  or email_cc like '%abc@xyz.com%') 

   FROM t_user tu left join t_organisation torg on tu.user_org_id=
  torg.organisation_id   where tu.user_org_id = 42  order by tu.user_last_name, 
  tu.user_first_name
```

Comment: Hi Rahul,
I'm getting this error with your proposition: "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

Comment: That's cause your 'email_to' and 'email_cc' cols are either defined as text/ntext ... edited accordingly but in reality it should be `varchar` type column.

Comment: Hi Rahul, actually, the email_to and email_cc columns contains mailing list and since it's not sure how long will the mailing list be, that's why is defined as ntext... Nevertheless, your suggestion has speed up my query. After analyzing the query I've gain, 20 % in about performance. thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, somehow this is not returning the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do the following for the email:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM   t_email 
    WHERE  
       (
            PATINDEX('%' + user_email + '%', email_to) != 0
            OR PATINDEX('%' + user_email + '%', email_cc) != 0
       )
```

Comment: Hi Greco, thanks for your help..The Patindex tip has fastened my query..aroung 15% improvement in performance.